# use a foreign key or duplicate table columns?

Tags: database-design

I have a CONTACT table with columns:

- id
- name varchar(50)
- mobileno

When my system attempt to send a message, it would write a log in another table MSG_LOG with columns:

- id
- name varchar(50)
- mobileNo
- message
- datetimecreated

My question #1: is this a good design? Could this be a better way (below).

MSG_LOG

- id
- contact_id (fk)
- message
- datetimecreated

Question #2: My concern is what if someday we need to expand Contact.name from varchar(50) to varchar(100). What are the chances that we will forget to expand MSG_LOG.contact_id as well?

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A far more important question is: what happens when someone's name or mobile number changes?

With the first design, you retain a record of their name and mobile number at the time the message was sent.

With the second design, you point back to the updated name and number.

(Depending on the history you need, you may even want a third option: contact id, name, and number all in the MSG_LOG.)

Answer (score 2):

Use a SQL alias type -- in SQL Server it's:

```
CREATE TYPE name_type FROM varchar(50) not null
```

Comment: This will depend on the DBMS, but most common ones (SQL Server, PostgeSQL, MySQL, etc.) have them.

Comment: Thanks! It was great help. But I do not want to be restricted to SQL Server only. Hoping the solution can support MySQL as well. (SQL Server, MySQL & PostgreSQL is a frequent use in my environment)

Comment: Oh there you answered it.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. Ans. 
Don't MobileNo and Name again in MSG_LOG table.

If ContactId become FK then easily you can fetch everything from both table.

So just create MSG_LOG table with

MSGID PK [ it sholud be auto incremented]
MSGTEXT
sendingdate_time
ContactID FK

and 
If Your messages are repeated the you should create a Messages table also and use ContactId, MessagesId as FK in MSGLOG table and reuse msg and contacts with less information as 3rd normalization. Always save new msg once in msg collections and reuse them.if msg are repeated then you should do it. it is also time saving for front end point of view  also.